# Filling table in a specific way with sql data using loops

Tags: php, html

I want to put data from the following database table in a html table in a specific way.

[image]

Below is my php code:

```
echo "<table style='border:2px solid black;width:100%;'>";

foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
  for ($i = 1; $i < 4; $i++) { // 3 + 1 = 4 (itération sur la valeur de $value['ligne'])
    if ($i == $value['ligne']) {
      echo "<tr>";
      for ($j = 1; $j < 4; $j++) { // itération sur la valeur de $value['colonne']
        //if ($j == $value['colonne'] ) {
        echo "<td style='padding:1em;border:1px solid black;'>".$value['contenu']."</td>";
        //}
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }   
  }
}
echo "</table>";
```

And here is the output that i'm having:

[image]

What I want to achieve is having "colonne1" only in the column 1 of the table; "colonne2" only in column 2, etc. In the same way, "Ligne1" should appear only in row 1; "Ligne2" in row 2, which is what i've been able to do. Any idea? Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a two dimensional array to achieve the object seeing you’re looking for.

First, build a data structure from the database results.

```
// assuming you’ve retrieved table into  $results
$table =array();
foreach($results as $v) {

  $row = $v[‘ligne’];
  $col = $v[‘colonne’];
  $content = $v[‘contenue’];

  $table[$row][$col] = $content;
}

// build html table
?>
```

Then you can print it out in the view:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($table as $row_array): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($row_array  as $col): ?>
            <td><?= $col ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```